# How to convert data using lambda expression or using any other logic?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have a DataTable which contains data in this format. I want to convert it to another format.
    What is the simplest way to achieve this? maybe using lambda expression. I am using
C# 4.0

```
dattable1:
    seq     id        Amt
=============================
    1     00782       10 
    2     00782       20
    3     00782       30

    1     003850      40
    2     003850      50
    3     003850      60

    1     005723      70
    2     005723      80
    3     005723      90


To be stored in another datatable or list in this format

1  00782  003850  005723  10  40  70
2  00782  003850  005723  20  50  80
3  00782  003850  005723  30  60  90
```

example 2

```
 dattable1:
        seq     id        Amt
    =============================
        1     00782       10 


        1     003850      40


        1     005723      70



    To be stored in another datatable or list in this format

    1  00782  003850  005723  10  40  70
```

Comment: Your new "format" makes no sense to me.  So you just want to place rows with the same `seq` together in a new row?  Will they always come in 3's?  Why do you need them to be in this "format"?

Comment: Is the number of rows/columns always going to be the same?  If not, will every sequence value always have the same number of entries?  If not, how will the dynamically sized output rows be handled?

Comment: @jeff: becoz i m getting this data from ref cursor i.e from stored procedue. No of columns will remain the same but no of rows may vary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will generate the input that matches what you asked for.

```
var datatable1 = new[]
{
    new { seq = 1, id = "00782", Amt = 10 }, 
    new { seq = 2, id = "00782", Amt = 20 }, 
    new { seq = 3, id = "00782", Amt = 30 }, 
    new { seq = 1, id = "003850", Amt = 40 }, 
    new { seq = 2, id = "003850", Amt = 50 }, 
    new { seq = 3, id = "003850", Amt = 60 }, 
    new { seq = 1, id = "005723", Amt = 70 }, 
    new { seq = 2, id = "005723", Amt = 80 }, 
    new { seq = 3, id = "005723", Amt = 90 }
};


var result = datatable1
    .GroupBy(arg => arg.seq)
    .Select(arg =>
        new
        {
            arg.Key,
            id1 = "00782",
            id2 = "003850",
            id3 = "005723",
            Amt1 = arg.Where(x => x.id == "00782").Sum(x => x.Amt),
            Amt2 = arg.Where(x => x.id == "003850").Sum(x => x.Amt),
            Amt3 = arg.Where(x => x.id == "005723").Sum(x => x.Amt),
        })
    .ToList();
```

[Edit]

For "all scenarios":

```
var result = datatable1
    .GroupBy(arg => arg.seq)
    .Select(arg =>
        new
        {
            arg.Key,
            Ids = arg.Select(x => x.id).ToList(),
            Amounts = arg.Select(x => x.Amt).ToList(),
        })
    .ToList();

foreach (var row in result)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", row.Key, string.Join("\t", row.Ids), string.Join("\t", row.Amounts));
```

Output:

```
1       00782   003850  005723  10      40      70
2       00782   003850  005723  20      50      80
3       00782   003850  005723  30      60      90
```

Comment: @Alex Aza: +1 Beat me to it!  Shouldn't your id's be dynamic though?  i.e., select the id's from the dataset to use rather than hard-code.

Comment: thanks can u simplify it further so that it will work for all scenarios & not only for this

Comment: @Ulhas Tuscano: Can you define what all the scenarios are in your question?  It is unclear what variables might be dynamic and what won't.  Maybe adding another two examples that demonstrate the different possibilities would help.

Comment: @Alex i have added one more example no of rows may vary depending on the condition

Comment: Won't work if the number of rows vary unless I misunderstood the original question. (I should say the number of ID's vary.)

Comment: Thanks u r gr8. I got what i want i can simplify it further on my own. thanks once again